# Filtering and searching in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, search, drop-down-menu, full-text-search, filtering

I am doing a `filtering` and `searching` in codeigniter but no idea! how to do that?

but i try my best but fail!!!

here i show the list which is shown by ajax that sucess

[image]

**MY DATA BASE ARE**

[image]
[image]

**MY CONTROLLER IS**

```html
  public function get_quick_search() 
{
        $sepcli= $this->input->post('spec');
        $distct= $this->input->post('dist');
        $locat= $this->input->post('locat');
         $data['list'] = $this->Doctor_model->search_listing();
        $data['quck_search'] = $this->search_model->get_quick_list($sepcli,$distct,$locat);
        $data['get_specs'] = $this->specialisation_model->get_specialisation();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('customer/header');
        $this->load->view('customer/side_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('customer/quick_search',$data);
        $this->load->view('customer/footer');
}
```

**MY MODEL LIKE**

```html
 public  function get_quick_list($locat,$distct,$sepcli)  
{  
    $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('tbl_doctor');  
        $this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');

        $this->db->where("(district LIKE '$distct' AND place LIKE '$locat' AND spec_specialise LIKE '$sepcli')");

    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array(); 

 
          return $query;
}
```

HERE NO ERROR SHOW BUT THE RETURN QUERY IS `NULL` SHOW LIKE THIS `(array(0) { })`

Comment: where is the issue ?

Comment: model is issue show

Comment: help me pls the query retun null value

Comment: print the query  first , bro then run on mysql directly see whats been mistaken in query !!! using $this->db->last_query();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might try like this ,Your Controller  function code

```
public function get_quick_search()
{
        $s_data['sepcli'] = $this->input->post('spec');
        $s_data['distct'] = $this->input->post('dist');
        $s_data['locat']  = $this->input->post('locat');


        $data['quck_search'] = $this->search_model->get_quick_list($s_data);
        $data['get_specs'] = $this->specialisation_model->get_specialisation();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('customer/header');
        $this->load->view('customer/side_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('customer/quick_search',$data);

        $this->load->view('customer/footer');
}
```

your model function code

```
public  function get_quick_list($s_data)  
{  
    $this->db->select('td.*, ts.*')
    $this->db->from('tbl_doctor as td');    
    $this->db->join('tbl_specialisation as ts', 'ts.spec_id = td.spec_id','left');

    if($s_data['sepcli'] !="")
       $this->db->like('ts.spec_specialise',$s_data['sepcli'],'both');
    if($s_data['distct'] !="")
       $this->db->like('td.district',$s_data['distct'],'both');
    if($s_data['locat'] !="")
       $this->db->like('td.place', $s_data['locat'], 'both');

    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array(); 
    return $query;
}
```

sure it will helps , you should try it !!!

Comment: just wait  i will try

Comment: my list data this type                                                                                                    <select name="spec" class="chosen-select form-control" id="form-field-select-3" id="spec" data-placeholder="Choose Category">
 <?php if(isset($get_specs)): ?>
            <?php
             foreach($get_specs->result() as $rows):
          ?>

         <option value="<?php echo $rows->spec_id; ?>"><?php echo $rows->spec_specialise; ?> </option>
                 <?php 
        endforeach;
          endif;
          ?>

Comment: why are you used result again in foreach loop. you already got the result_array in controller when call to modal function . make sense !!

Comment: just print it out the  $get_specs in view files , make sure its returns the correct data !!

Comment: retun query is empty

Comment: try to print the query , using $this->db->last_query , see whats query is build then test it out on mysql , see if its has a error  or what >>>

Comment: have you print the query at least  ?

Comment: what i std and ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129606/discussion-between-amit-chauhan-and-antroo-ghosh).