# multiple search in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, search

I am doing multiple search in code igniter the list show the three select box
specialization ,district ,place that success full listed

**mymodel**

```
public  function get_quick_list($locat,$distct,$sepcli)  
{  
    $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('tbl_doctor');  
        $this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');

        $this->db->where("(district LIKE '$distct' AND place LIKE '$locat' AND spec_specialise LIKE '$sepcli')");

    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array(); 

 var_dump($query);die();
          return $query;
}
```

**my controller**

```
public function get_quick_search() 
{
        $sepcli= $this->input->post('spec');
        $distct= $this->input->post('dist');
        $locat= $this->input->post('locat');
         $data['list'] = $this->Doctor_model->search_listing();
        $data['quck_search'] = $this->search_model->get_quick_list($sepcli,$distct,$locat);
        $data['get_specs'] = $this->specialisation_model->get_specialisation();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->view('customer/header');
        $this->load->view('customer/side_view',$data);
        $this->load->view('customer/quick_search',$data);
        $this->load->view('customer/footer');
}
```

the return query show null value

Comment: This is Duplicate question asked it twice !! and i also gave the solution for it . here's the link , if i wrong

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902542/filtering-and-search-in-code-igniter?noredirect=1#comment69152055_40902542

Answer (score 0):

In your model your code should be

```
public  function get_quick_list($locat,$distct,$sepcli)  
{  
    $this->db->select('*');    
        $this->db->from('tbl_doctor');  
        $this->db->join("tbl_specialisation", "tbl_specialisation.spec_id = tbl_doctor.spec_id",'left');

        $this->db->where("(district LIKE '%".$distct."%' AND place LIKE '%".$locat."%' AND spec_specialise LIKE '%".$sepcli."%')");

    $query=$this->db->get()->result_array(); 

 var_dump($query);die();
          return $query;
}
```

> Let's explain how the % wildcard works in the SQL LIKE condition.
>   Remember that the % wildcard matches any string of any length
>   (including zero length).

check link https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40902542/filtering-and-search-in-code-igniter/40924881#40924881